# Convert Data to json using Python

Tags: python, json, string, split

I'm hitting one Api and getting data like this from API.

```
'tt_cls|rd~1|rk~1|kk~1{#tt2_cls|rd~1|rk~1|kk~0{#tt3_cls|rd~1|rk~1|kk~0\n\n'
```

now I want to change this in json format and want output like this.

```
{
    {
        "vwId": "tt_cls",
        "vdef": [
            {
                "nm": "rd",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "rk",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "kk",
                "st": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "vwId": "tt2_cls",
        "vdef": [
            {
                "nm": "rd",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "rk",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "kk",
                "st": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "vwId": "tt3_cls",
        "vdef": [
            {
                "nm": "rd",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "rk",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "kk",
                "st": false
            }
        ]
    }
  }
```

I have tried to split the string with {# and then make pair with split part

```
str=str.split('{#')
res=[]
for i in range(1,len(str)):
    b=str[i].split('~')
    
    obj={
        "name": b[0],
        "visible": b[1]=='1'
      }

res.append(obj)
```

but with this I'm not getting desired json format.
like it will split the nm and st pair but not getting value of vwId.

Comment: Python booleans are `True` and `False`, JSON booleans are `true` and `false`. Try `print(json.dumps(res))` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output isn't valid json, your enclosing brackets should be square brackets (i.e a list of dictionaries). This can be achieved with a nested loop/comprehension:

```
import json

input_str = 'tt_cls|rd~1|rk~1|kk~1{#tt2_cls|rd~1|rk~1|kk~0{#tt3_cls|rd~1|rk~1|kk~0\n\n'
output_rec = [
    {
        'vwId': d.split('|')[0],
        'vdef': [{'nm': x.split('~')[0],
                  'st': bool(int(x.split('~')[1]))}
                for x in d.split('|')[1:]]
    }
    for d in input_str.strip().split('{#')
]
print(json.dumps(output_rec, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "vwId": "tt_cls",
        "vdef": [
            {
                "nm": "rd",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "rk",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "kk",
                "st": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "vwId": "tt2_cls",
        "vdef": [
            {
                "nm": "rd",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "rk",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "kk",
                "st": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "vwId": "tt3_cls",
        "vdef": [
            {
                "nm": "rd",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "rk",
                "st": true
            },
            {
                "nm": "kk",
                "st": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```